# Printing to file with vbNewLine results in double NewLine

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following simple line to print a new line to a log file:

```
Print #fileNumber, vbNewLine
```

However, this results in 2 newlines instead of one. My code does not have any other vbNewLines or anything that would print newlines.

If I do not have this print line, then I print no newlines, so this means this line is printing 2 newlines.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: What is vbNewLine defined as?

Comment: @ColeJohnson `vbNewline` is the same as `vbCrLf` or `chr(13) & chr(10)`

Comment: Oh I had no idea. How do I define it to be only one newline?

Comment: You cannot redefine it, it is a built in constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested this, and Print always adds a linebreak.

So simply using `Print #fileNumber,` will result in 1 blank line.

The problem is that Print already prints on a new line, so when you add `vbnewline` you're getting 2 lines.